# Having error with expo project when building with eas build

Tags: react-native, expo, fastlane, eas

I’m getting a lot of error that I can’t find the answer in stackoverflow, github etc …

This is the first error I’m getting on Fastlane step, all the others might be fixed if I fixed this one :

`Compiling expo-dev-menu Pods/expo-dev-menu » DevMenuManager.swift
❌  (ios/Pods/Headers/Private/expo-dev-menu/EXDevMenu/DevMenuRCTBridge.h:3:9)

2 |

> 3 | #import <React/RCTBridge+Private.h>
> |         ^ 'React/RCTBridge+Private.h' file not found
> 4 |
> 5 | NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
> 6 | `

I don’t know what is is related to.
To provide some more information, my previous build was successful.
With my next build, I needed to upgrade expo update.
I did so, and I get these errors on Pod install step :

`[!] Unable to find a specification for EXUpdatesInterface depended upon by EXUpdates`

`[!] Unable to find a specification for expo-dev-launcher depended upon by expo-dev-client`

`[!] Unable to find a specification for expo-dev-menu-interface depended upon by expo-dev-launcher`

`[!] Unable to find a specification for expo-dev-menu depended upon by expo-dev-client`

After installing theses packages with expo instal … and launch the new build, I managed to pass the Pod install step, but now I get the error I mentionned at the beginning

Workflow : Managed
SDK : 46